# How to prove the following result in Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R^4$ be a linear map such that null space of $T$ is

{$(x,y,z,w)\varepsilon \mathbb R^4: x+y+z+w=0)$}  and the Rank of $(T-4I_4)$ is $3$.

If the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $x(x-4)^{\alpha}$ then $\alpha$ is $1$.

Now what i have done is Rank of $(T-4I_4)$ is $3$ so Nullity $(T-4I_4)$ is $1$.

Which imply that Geometric Multiplicity of Eigen Value $4$ is $1$. Thus in the

Minimal Polynomial $\alpha$ is $3$ Where i am wrong?

Comment: @ John Hughes yes it is clear as Rank of $T$ is $3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the rank of $(T−4I_4)$ iS $3$, we know that $4$ is an eigenvalue (since the kernel therefore has dim = 1).

On the other hand, the kernel of $T$ evidently has dimension 3, since the vectors $(1,0,0,-1), (0, 1, 0, -1),$ and $(0, 0, 1, -1)$ are all in it. So the characteristic polynomial must be 
$$
c(x) = (x-0)^3 (x - 4)
$$
The minimal polynomial is given as $x (x-4)^\alpha$, and must divide the characteristic polynomial. Hence $\alpha = 0$ or $1$. If $\alpha$ were 0, then $T$ would have to satisfy $T =0$, which it does not, but the null-space statement. Hence $\alpha = 1$.

(Sorry about my earlier incorrect answer.)

Comment: but its null space is not satisfying the given condition

Comment: it comes out span of $(1,1,1,1)$

Comment: My mistake. I read $x + y + z + w = 0$ as $(1,1,1,1) \cdot (x,y,z,w) = 0$, which I then mistranslated into "the kernel is spanned by $(1,1,1,1)$ rather than "the cokernel is spanned by (1,1,1,1)." Replacing my answer with a correct one now.

Comment: yes got it. thanks